# processing capability of R on Hive

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

If R just brings all the data from Hive into memory (especially statistical analysis) and the processes it within memory which is limited by RAM Size then what is the advantage of having R on Hive node?

Comment: You can have Microsoft R on top for memory issues

Comment: btw R is not installed in Hive its installed into all nodes of Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the data using Hive partitions and then data chunks on which you want to build the models will be co-located (in same server). On these partitions you can then run R streaming or use SparkR to build model or do scoring. You will in effect get parallelization.

Its true doing so will bring the data into memory but that will be memory of different YARN/MESOS container's memory all working in parallel. e.g. Memory in the Hadoop distributed case with Spark will not mean all data dumped into driver memory but rather each container own memory.

Comment: Can you throw some more light on the whole process or would you have some link.

Comment: look into `partition by` clause of hive and do partition of data at the level you want to build model. Say you want to build model by country then `partition by country` and so on. Then look into HDFS file you will find different files like `hive_table_hdfs_path/country=USA` and `hive_table_hdfs_path/country=UK` etc..  Have distinct country names in a new Hive table. Then instantiate mapper equal to distinct countries (it will automatically get one country name).

Comment: Then on R installed in each node you can read these files using any file read command (file name to read = paste0(hive_table_hdfs_path/country=`country_passed`). Do modelling in mapper or reducer now. Cant be more specific than this.

Comment: sparkR is another option you can explore.